# Pack GIT submodules into svn

Tags: git

Here's the problem. I'm part of a large team working on a (you guessed it) large project. We're using all sorts of git-enabled projects such as jquery, backbone, underscore, timezoneJS, momentjs, backbone.grid, etc., etc. We've also got some shared 'architectural' resources that are needed in another project.

The company runs primarily on SVN, but it makes sense for our project to be on GIT I think - we can stop keeping these external resources around in our repo and instead grab them from 'the source of truth'. More importantly, the shared resources we are using between projects can be edited on one to fix a bug, and then that edit can go up and get shared across the projects with relative ease.

I think there's a way of doing this via SVN, but I'm far from an SVN expert.

Anyway, the question is as follows: Is it possible, or are there tools, to take a git repo with git submodules, pack it all up and commit it to SVN with the appropriate changelog attached? We also need to read back changes, as a few files are automatically updated based on various build things. I've investigated subgit, but that doesn't seem to support this.

A little bit of information regarding the project setups:

project#1:

- src

  - architecture -- company-wide stuff and whatsits

    - lib --jquery, moment, etc
  - project#1files -- project specific files
  - index.html
  - bootstrap data file

project#2:

- src

  - architecture -- company-wide stuff and whatsits

    - lib --jquery, moment, etc
  - project#2files -- project specific files
  - index.html
  - bootstrap data file

.. you can see the basic flow :)

Comment: Do shared 'architectural' resources also depend on those projects based on Git? Is that possible to extract those resources into separate SVN repository, install SubGit into it. Then switch your project into Git, so the shared data can be added as one more submodule? Other projects may use shared resources as svn:externals, I suppose.

Comment: For the most part, the shared 'architectural' stuff is where all of the dependencies on GIT are. The projects that depend on it have everything that they need in that arch folder, from jQuery to moment.js. On top of that, all externals are contained to one folder - arch/lib

Comment: Updated question with some setup information.

Comment: The most of the libraries you listed are hosted on GitHub, which has basic SVN access functionality, so there's no problem to add those libraries as svn:externals. If there's a library without SVN access, you can mirror it locally and install SubGit into it to get an SVN access, and again use svn:externals, as @radioversum suggested. I think it's better to use built-in subversion means instead of any scripts because they work everywhere (with IDE, with CI,...) and handle a lot of cases that you can run into with external scripts.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to migrate to GIT, since you mention that it makes more sense for your team, you should be able to use [git svn](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) to fetch the commits and push them to a GIT repository (likely one per project?).

A far less ideal and hack-ish option would be to commit your GIT clones to your SVN repository. SVN is fairly good with binary files so it would not be abdominal to do so...still, hardly recommended since you would have a bunch of GIT meta-data in your SVN repository and would have to fetch and commit whenever you want to update your external dependencies (unnecessarily grows the size of your repository for little gain).

I am hardly an SVN or GIT expert myself so I don't know if there is a (probably) better way. If your company is adverse to letting your team switch to GIT just because the rest of the company uses SVN then you might be better off trying to change the corporate culture.

Comment: Then again, since your post is 9 years old it may no longer be relevant...